# How to change color of TODAY in Calendar?

Tags: macos, ical

How can I change the color of TODAY in Calender?

Answer (score 1):

In OS X it’s possible to change the highlight color. You can do this in the General ▸ Appearance panel in System Preferences.

Now you can enable the system highlight color for the today selection with the following command.

defaults write com.apple.ical CalUIUseSystemHighlightColorForToday -bool TRUE

Comment: This works prior to 10.9, but not in 10.9 or later.

Comment: @VickiBrown this post was written in 2015 !